# which method of creating an instance is a "better" method and why?

Tags: c#, design-patterns

I was just wondering whether one of these methods of creating an instance is a “better” solution, if so then why?

```
 method 1:   MyClass myClass = new MyClass();
 method 2:   MyClass myClass2 = MyClass.Create();


public class MyClass
{
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public static MyClass Create()
    {
        return new MyClass();
    }
}
```

Kind Regards

Comment: There is no difference between the two methods in your case.

Comment: There are times when one way is better, and times when the other way is better. The division between the two approaches is, at best, subjective. When there isn't something forcing the choice, method 2 allows constructors to be an implementation detail (this is sometimes cleaner),. Generally I would use the constructor unless I had good reason to go with the helper method.

Comment: @RahulTripathi - in this case there is no difference, but the `Create` method could, in general have more logic to return a type derived from `MyClass`, or even `null` - which a constructor cannot return.

Comment: In your example it doesn't makes much difference. Come with a better example :)

Comment: The first case, since if you pass anything, you can do it while constructing the object. You also don't need to write the Create method.

Comment: Thank you for all the answers :) I'll take it on board.

Comment: Just use the constructor if you don't have good reasons to do otherwise. You explicitely expose dependencies this way, and the preferred approach when doing IoC.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Method 2 could be *more flexible*, e.g. when implementing *Factory Method* pattern

```
  public abstract class MyClass {
    ...
    protected MyClass() {
    }

    public static MyClass Create() {
      if (...)
        return new MyClassOne();
      else if (...)   
        return new MyClassTwo();
      ...
    } 

    public abctract void DoSomething();
  }

  ...

  MyClass my = MyClass.Create();
  // I have no need to choose which concrete class (MyClassOne, MyClassTwo etc.) 
  // will do something for me 
  my.DoSomething();
```